# How can i extract only tuples that have the value 3 and above?

Tags: python, list

```
lst = [(2),('hello',3),(4),('world',5)]
```

I want extract only the tuples that have the value 3 and above

how can i do that ?

Comment: (4) is not a tuple, IMHO

Comment: anyway, how can i do that ?

Comment: Did you mean to write `(2,)` and `(4,)` so they're tuples? Should `(4,)` be included in the result?

Comment: yeah 4 has to be included in the list

Comment: Why do you put `2` and `4` in parentheses? It's confusing if they're not supposed to be tuples.

Comment: Can you also have a tuple like `(4, 'world')`. Should it be in the result? What about `(1, 2, 3, 4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[n for n in lst if type(n) is tuple and n[1] >= 3]


[n for n in lst if isinstance(n, tuple) and n[1] >= 3 or isinstance(n, int) and n >= 3]
```

Comment: @Essence: it worksn't. Number 4 is missing. You explizitly said you want 4 included in the result.

Comment: `isinstance(n, tuple)` is preferable to `type(n) is tuple` because it will handle subtypes.

Comment: `[n for n in lst if isinstance(n, tuple) and n[1] >= 3 or n >= 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Accounting for `(4)` not being a tuple, and the value greater than or equal to `3` potentially being anywhere in each tuple:

```
[n 
 for n in lst 
 if (isinstance(n, int) and n >= 4) or \
    (isinstance(n, tuple) and \
     any(x for x in n if isinstance(x, int) and x >= 3))]
# [('hello', 3), 4, ('world', 5)]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will handle the cases you need. I made it so that you get the tuples first. It's more object oriented than other answers.

```py
from typing import List


class More:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def be(self, value: int):
        self.value = value
        return self

    def than(self, value: int):
        if value >= self.value:
            return value
        return None


class TupleHandlr:
    @staticmethod
    def is_tuple(t):
        return isinstance(t, tuple)


def larger_numbers(liszt):
    numbrz = [n for n in liszt if isinstance(n,int)]
    more = More().be(3)
    largernumbrz = [n for n in numbrz if more.than(n)]
    return largernumbrz


class TupleValueExtractr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MinimumValue = 3

    def from_list(self, liszt: List) -> List:
        th = TupleHandlr()
        tuples = [t for t in liszt if th.is_tuple(t)]
        more = More().be(self.MinimumValue)
        largertuples = [t for t in tuples if more.than(t[1])]
        return largertuples + larger_numbers(liszt)


lst = [(2), ('hello', 3), (4), ('world', 5)]
extract = TupleValueExtractr()
print(extract.from_list(lst))
```

Output:

```
[('hello', 3), ('world', 5), 4]
```